# Problem with custom link cursor in Chrome

Tags: css, hover, mouse-cursor

I want to use a custom cursor on hover for links. It works fine on Safari and Firefox, but on Chrome it jumps back to the default cursor for a millisecond, and then goes to my custom cursor.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ford1234/pen/vwzRgJ

I've recreated the problem in Codepen but it also happens on the site I'm applying it to.

```
<div>
  <a href="#"><p>Hello</p></a>
</div>

<style>
html {
    cursor: url('http://telephoneavenue.art/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/black-01.png'), auto;
}

a:hover {
    cursor: url('http://telephoneavenue.art/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/blacktriangle-small17px.png'), auto;
```

}

Expected result: A transition from the circle to the triangle.
Actual result: A transition from the circle, to the default hand pointer, to the triangle.

Comment: Cannot replicate but perhaps `will-change: cursor;` might help.

Comment: @Paulie_D Doesn't make a difference unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove ":hover" on your selector. 
your selector must be;

> a{
>       cursor: url('http://telephoneavenue.art/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/blacktriangle-small17px.png'),
>   auto; }

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out a **transition-duration** or a **transition-delay**? This is used to define the duration of a specified transition. This is the length of time it will take for the targeted element to transition between two defined states.

```
.example {
    transition-duration: 0s;
    // or
    transition-delay: -1s;
}
```

Also keep in mind that some features are only supported by certain versions of the browser.

[image: Browser Support]